# pandas read_csv path issue

Tags: python, pandas

I can easily read a csv file if I go:

```
pd.read_csv(r'C:\\yourpath\yourcsvfile.csv')
```

But I wanna try path variables instead of hardcode my path. So I tried:

```
processed_data_path=os.path.join(os.path.pardir,'data','processed')
train_file_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(processed_data_path,'train.csv'))
test_file_path=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(processed_data_path,'test.csv'))
```

the print result is:

```
C:\yourpath\train.csv
C:\yourpath\test.csv
```

So it looks alright. But when I tried the code below it throws a file does not exist error:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv(train_file_path)
```

where is the problem?

Comment: forgot to mention that I'm using windows with python 3.6

Comment: show the value that you are assigning to `train_file_path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `pathlib` module, which is very convenient and natively supported by modern Pandas versions:

Demo:

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path
except ImportError:             # Python 2
    from pathlib2 import Path

In [49]: p = Path('D:\\')
```

use overloaded operator `/` for joining paths:

```
In [50]: f = p / 'temp' / '.data' / '1.txt'

In [51]: f
Out[51]: WindowsPath('D:/temp/.data/1.txt')

In [52]: pd.read_csv(f)
Out[52]:
        Val
0  0.120000
1  0.320000
2  0.439999
3  0.560000
4  0.599999
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe adding a check before calling the parser will help you to identify the issue
and it is always a good pratice to check path before parsing to make sure we dont't hit the wall of exceptions :

```
if os.path.exists(train_file_path):
           train_df = pd.read_csv(train_file_path)
else:
           print(train_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

For VSCode users: The issue might be that VSCode sets current working directory to workspace root folder. My solution was:

To set current working directory to whatever file you are executing at the time:

File > Preferences > Settings > Python > Data Science > Execute in File Dir

Thanks to user brch: [Python in VSCode: Set working directory to python file's path everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776521/python-in-vscode-set-working-directory-to-python-files-path-everytime)