# Environment Variable not loading with load_dotenv() in Linux

Tags: python, linux, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm trying to make a discord bot, and when I try to load a .env with load_dotenv() it doesn't work because it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fanjin/Documents/Python Projects/Discord Bot/bot.py", line 15, in <module>
    client.run(TOKEN)
  File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "/home/fanjin/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip
```

Here's my code for the bot:

```
import os

import discord
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'{client.user} has connected to Discord!')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

And the save.env file: (It's a fake token)

```
# .env
DISCORD_TOKEN={XXXXXXXX}
```

Both files are in the same directory, and I even tried to explicitly specify the .env's path with

```
env_path = Path('path/to/file') / '.env'
load_dotenv(dotenv_path=env_path)
```

but that also didn't work

Comment: Insofar as this is principally a question about the `dotenv` library, which isn't part of Python or Linux itself, consider tagging for that library.

Comment: BTW, this is a guess, but does it work if you quote your token's value? That is: `DISCORD_TOKEN='{...}'`

Comment: ...it would also be helpful to include the stack trace for the exception; if we know which line originally threw the exception, we'll know which value was unexpectedly `None` instead of containing a string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sorry for getting to you late, I'm using the `python-dotenv` library I installed with pip. I tried quoting it but it didn't work, and I updated the post to include the full stack trace

Comment: Okay, so that error is telling you that `token` is None; it's not being directly thrown from the dotenv code itself.

Comment: Have you checked that the current working directory of your script is the same as the directory the code is in? Log the path so you know it's correct, and then we can move on to other issues (like checking whether dotenv can handle curly braces in values).

Comment: If you're running your script as a systemd service, by the way, have you considered using the `EnvironmentFile` directive to have systemd load the variables from your file before the Python interpreter is even started?

Comment: Yes, it is in the same working directory, and I also tried it without curly brackets. Also, what do you mean by running my script as a systemd service? And how do I use the `EnvironmentFile` directive?

Comment: Waitaminute. When you say "same working directory", that doesn't make it clear to me that you know what the term "current working directory" means. I'm asking if you know, with absolute certainty, that the current working directory of the process (the directory returned by `os.getcwd()`) is the same as the directory that contains both your code and your `.env`. That's not necessarily the case, and there are good reasons to make it _not_ the case (a cwd of `/` avoids whole classes of bugs, f/e, the potential for a working directory to become invalid).

Comment: An EnvironmentFile directive is part of systemd service configuration. If you're telling systemd to run your service for you, you create a `.service` file that tells you _how_ you want that service to be run (so if you called it `my-discord-bot.service`, you could then use `systemctl start my-discord-bot` to start it, or `journalctl -u my-discard-bot` to read its logs).

Comment: One of the things you can put in that service definition file is a list of other files to read to get environment variables. (You can also configure whether you want your service automatically restarted on reboot, which services it should be started _after_, etc etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put the full path.

Use

- either `os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/MY_PROJECT/.env')`
- or: `load_dotenv('/home/MY_USER/Documents/MY_PROJECT/.env')`

and it will work.

Or you change your current working directory in your code editor to where the ".env" file is (which should be the project folder).

Or you open the project folder in the menu of your code editor, this should make the project folder the current working directory.

On Linux, you can also go to the project folder in the terminal and start the code editor from there, type for example `codium` or whatever you use in the command prompt.

#### TL:DR

##### Quote from the other answer

> Since, I moved my .env file's inside another subfolder config, then I had to provide the full path to load_dotenv() to make it work.

This gave me the idea of checking the working directory.

##### Current working directory

`os.getcwd()` gave me a folder further up the tree. And then I copied the ".env" file into that working directory and it worked.

Changing the working directory depends on your code editor. I use codium, which is the open source version of vscode, then you may follow for example [Python in VSCode: Set working directory to python file's path everytime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776521/python-in-vscode-set-working-directory-to-python-files-path-everytime)

##### Full path

You can also put the full path.

Funny enough, I had checked that before coming here, but I copied the path that you get from the terminal, starting with `'~/Documents/MY_PROJECT`, which does not find the file but does not alert either, any tried environment variables were just empty - just because the ".env" file itself was never read.

Answer (score 10):

###### I was facing a similar issue and found out these three possible solutions/reasons:

1. Check if the syntax in your .env file is correct or not, the original documentation will be the best source - [Python Dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) (sample below)

   ```
    DOMAIN=example.org
    ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@${DOMAIN}
    ROOT_URL=${DOMAIN}/app
   ```
2. The solution which worked for me, was using `find_dotenv()` instead of file path inside `load_dotenv()`, the reason is `load_dotenv()` doesn't load the .env file properly. `find_dotenv()` is a function that automatically finds .env file if it's located in the same folder as your code file.

   ```
    from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv

    load_dotenv(find_dotenv())
   ```
3. You can limit your search to the current project folder using `sys.path[1]` to make sure you're reading the intended file.

   ```
    import sys
    from dotenv import load_dotenv
    load_dotenv(sys.path[1]) #try .path[0] if 1 doesn't work
   ```

Since, I moved my `.env` file's inside another subfolder `config`, then I had to provide the full path to `load_dotenv()` to make it work.

```
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv
path = sys.path[1]+'/config/.env'  #try .path[0] if 1 doesn't work
load_dotenv(path)
```

[edited]

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue, and in my case, this solved it:

Instead of doing `load_dotenv()` I needed to do  `load_dotenv(override=True)`. This was because I had set one of the variables from the `.env` file manually, and so it was not updating with the value set in the `.env` file.

The parameter `override` defaults to False. Here is the definition, taken from the dotenv github:

```
override: Whether to override the system environment variables with the variables
            from the `.env` file.
```

Answer (score 4):

I had same error trying to load my environment configuration on ubuntu 20.04 and python-dotenv 0.15.0. I was able to rectify this using python interpreter which will log out any error encountered while trying to load your environments. Whenever your environment variable is loaded successfully, load_dotenv() returns `True`.

For me it was an issue with my configuration file (syntax error) that broke the loading process. All i needed to do was to go to my environment variable config file and fix the broken syntax..

Try passing `verbose=True` when loading your environment variable (from python's interpreter) to get more info from load_dotenv.

Answer (score 2):

I had:

variable = 'variable'

changing them to be:

variable=variable

fixed the issue. (removing spaces, remove '')

Answer (score 1):

So this took me a while.  My load_dotenv() was returning True.

I had commas after some records which is not correct.

Once I removed the commas the variables were working.